# Remove anything following first character that is not a letter in a string in python

Tags: python, regex, string

There are several question about stripping non alpha-numeric characters from a string using regex. What I want to do is to remove every character, including letters, after the first character that is not a letter or a single space (this includes numbers and double spaces).

For example:

```
My string is #not very beautiful
```

should become

```
My string is
```

or

```
Are you 9 years old?
```

should become

```
Are you
```

and

```
this is the last  example
```

should become

```
this is the last
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: did you mean to omit whitespace as well?

Comment: I mean omit anything that follows a character that is not a letter or a single space. Anything before remains exactly the same. If there is a white space before that character and you know how to eliminate that as well, that is an added bonus.

Comment: you can do this with capturing groups...

Comment: Would've been nice to use `itertools.takewhile` if not for the multiple whitespace thing.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Please show what you've tried and be more specific with your question. Also, please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/3fTMHE/1

Comment: Also, saying that you "didn't get anywhere" is not the same as showing what you tried.

Comment: @Blorgbeard True, I could have posted a bunch of bad examples, but I did not think that would have helped anyone, except make me look stupid :)

Comment: It helps if you post the best attempt you've made so far, because it's a very good indication for answerers of how much you already know, and therefore how much they need to explain in their answer. And you might find out you were close to a perfectly valid solution.

Comment: I was actually close to Psidom answer, but I don't think I realized that. It does look I need to learn more about itertools though. Sometimes it is useful to get answers that are far from what you tried as you can learn something new, but I get your point. Thank you!

Comment: Or try like [`^(?:[A-Za-z]+ ?)+`](https://regex101.com/r/oDDtk3/1)

Comment: is that "Are you " or "Are you"?  "this is the last "?  
 i.e. do you want the last single space?

Comment: @JLPeyret  Preferably, I do not want the last single space, however I am happy with a solution that keeps it. I can later clean the trailing spaces if necessary.

Answer (score 6):

How about `split` on `[^A-Za-z ]|` and take the first element? You can trim possible white spaces later:

```
import re
re.split("[^A-Za-z ]|  ", "My string is #not very beautiful")[0].strip()
# 'My string is'

re.split("[^A-Za-z ]|  ", "this is the last  example")[0].strip()
# 'this is the last'

re.split("[^A-Za-z ]|  ", "Are you 9 years old?")[0].strip()
# 'Are you'
```

---

`[^A-Za-z ]|` contains two patterns, the first pattern is a single character which is neither a letter nor a white space; the second pattern is a double white space; Split on one of these two patterns, the first element after the split should be what you are looking for.

Comment: So, if I have 7 white spaces I will have just 5 white trailing spaces and then I can clean them later, correct?

Comment: If you have 7 white spaces the first element will just be what you are looking for, since the split of `\s{2}` happens right after the letter and there won't be any trailing spaces. But you might get trailing spaces, in case of ` #` or ` 9`

Comment: This solution only accounts for the space character rather than any whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Create a whitelist and stop when you see something not in that whitelist:

```
import itertools
import string

def rstrip(s, whitelist=None):
    if whitelist is None:
        whitelist = set(string.ascii_letters + ' ')  # set the whitelist to a default of all letters A-Z and a-z and a space
    # split on double-whitespace and take the first split (this will work even if there's no double-whitespace in the string)
    # use `itertools.takewhile` to include the characters that in the whitelist
    # use `join` to join them inot one single string

    return ''.join(itertools.takewhile(whitelist.__contains__, s.split('  ', 1)[0]))
```

Comment: Note the requirement of stopping on multiple whitespace groups.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: oh?! I didn't see that before answering, thanks. Fixed!

Comment: @inspectorG4dget  I assume s the string I am passing in and the function returns the string I want. Would you mind adding a couple of comments to help me understand the code?

Comment: @user: Hope the comments help

Comment: The space character isn't the only whitespace character, so this still isn't fixed.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
str1 = "this is the last  example"
regex = re.compile(r"(([a-zA-Z]|(\s[a-zA-Z]))+)")
capture = re.match(regex, str1)
res = capture.group(1)
```

I tested it with your other examples as well and it seemed to give the correct results. Note that this is not keeping the trailing whitespace, which is what your examples show, even though that is not what you say that you want.

Comment: This works on any whitespace character, not just the space character.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes, by design because that's usually what people want. If you only wanted to work on the space character you would replace the `\s` with ` `.

Answer (score 1):

Obligatory expression

```
def truncate_nonalpha_space(s):
    return s[:next((x for x, a in enumerate(s.split("  ")[0]) if not a.isalpha() and not a == " "), len(s))].rstrip()
```

Steps:

1. An expression is formed to get the indices of the values that are not a letter by the `.isalpha()` method or equal to `" "`
2. Left side of s split on `"  "` is used to dispose of any double-whitespace instances when the expression is popped
3. This remaining portion is enumerated to get list indices for the string (which is itself now a list)
4. The first of these values is used to slice s at, otherwise all of s `s[:len(s)]` is returned stripped of right whitespace `.rstrip()`

Comment: Same as the other answers; only takes the space character into account for whitespace.

Comment: That is intended as the question specified "that is not a letter or a single space".

Answer (score 1):

```
^.+?(?=[^A-Za-z ]|$|\s{2})
```

You can just grab the output using this.Use `re.findall` to grab the output.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/INzotJ/1

Comment: Same as the other answers; only takes the space character into account for whitespace.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 care to explain ur comment?

Answer (score 0):

Hacky, but uses **yield**:

```
import string

li_test = [
    ("My string is #not very beautiful","My string is"),
    ("Are you 9 years old?","Are you "),
    ("this is the last  example","this is the last "),
]

tolerated = string.ascii_letters

def rstrip_(s_in):
    last = None
    for char in s_in:
        if char in tolerated:
            last = char
            yield char
        elif char == ' ':
            if last == ' ':
                raise StopIteration()
            last = char
            yield char
        else:                    
            raise StopIteration()

for input_, exp in li_test:
    got = "".join(rstrip_(input_))
    msg = ":%s:<>:%s:" % (exp, got)
    print (":%s:=>:%s:" % (input_, got))
    #cheating a bit because I dunno if the last space is wanted.
    assert exp.rstrip() == got.rstrip(), msg
```

output:

```
 :My string is #not very beautiful:=>:My string is :
 :Are you 9 years old?:=>:Are you :
 :this is the last  example:=>:this is the last :
```

And, yes, I should have wrapped the whole thing in a second function and joined the characters there...

Comment: Same as the other answers; only takes the space character into account for whitespace.

Comment: Same as the other person you commented on, I don't get what you are saying 8/(.  The OP's question, "a single space", does not, on re-read, really clue me in about what *you* are complaining about.  In any case, if general whitespace removal, on \t and the like, was required, it would be simple enough to change `char == ' '` to `char in whitespaces`.